# Python win32com.client Excel xlTopCount

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I'm trying to return only the top 10 values in my pivot table. Here is the VBA

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Account Number"). _
        PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlTopCount, DataField:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("$$"), Value1:=11
```

I've tried several different appraoches like the below to no avail.

```
ws.PivotTables(pt_name).PivotFields('Charges').Type=win32c.xlTopCount
ws.PivotTables(pt_name).PivotFields('Charges').AddPivotFilters(ws.PivotTables(pt_name).PivotFields("$$",11).NumberFormat = win32c.xlTopCount
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't include the error message you get (*why not?*) but I am guessing you are getting a NameError at `win32c.xlTopCount` because there is no module `win32c`. Unless, of course you have some something like `import win32com as win32c` in which case you will get an AttributeError.

`xlTopCount` is a VBA constant, not a PythonWin constant, and in general PythonWin does not have Python analogues for such constants. You're expected to look them up. Checking the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpivotfiltertype) for what you are trying to do will quickly show that the value of `xlTopCount` is 1.

So use `1` instead of the nonexistent constant `win32c.xlTopCount`.